# Not connected to the server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\oooo\datatable.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\oooo\datatable.php(76): dbinit(Array) #1 {main} thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\oooo\datatable.php</b> on line 24
```

My code:

```
<?php

//For more Info: Please visit: http://www.discussdesk.com/bootstrap-datatable-with-add-edit-remove-option-in-php-mysql-ajax.htm

// VARIABLES
$aColumns = array('id', 'name', 'email', 'mobile', 'start_date');
$sIndexColumn = "id";
$sTable = "TABLE_NAME";
$gaSql['user'] = "USER_NAME";
$gaSql['password'] = "PASSWORD";
$gaSql['db'] = "DATABASE_NAME";
$gaSql['server'] = "localhost";


// DATABASE CONNECTION
function dbinit(&$gaSql) {
    // ERROR HANDLING
    function fatal_error($sErrorMessage = '') {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error');
        die($sErrorMessage);
    }

    // MYSQL CONNECT
    if ( !$gaSql['link'] = @mysqli_connect($gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']) ) {
        fatal_error('Could not open connection to server');
    }

    // MYSQL DATABASE SELECT
    if ( !mysqli_select_db($gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link']) ) {
        fatal_error('Could not select database');
    }
}
```

Comment: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\oooo\datatable.php:24
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\oooo\datatable.php(76): dbinit(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\oooo\datatable.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />

Comment: above error i am geeting in chrome developer tool

Comment: `mysql_*()` function are already depreciated. Better use mysqli or PDO

Comment: how to use PDO here/mysqli??

Comment: In the above code you posted, you are using `mysqli`. Which is fine! But the error message you gave is saying that you were using the depreciated `mysql_connect()` function! That should be changed to mysqli. As the error states, look at the file `C:\xampp\htdocs\oooo\datatable.php`, on line #24. See if you are using `mysql_connect()`. Then you need to use `mysqli_connect()` instead. Here's the example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: after adding in my program as mysqli_connect(),ia m getting followin error,

Comment: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\oooo\datatable.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
Could not select database

Comment: i have a databse name:dbs
table name: tbl

Comment: Show us the relevant piece of code. You can edit your original question and append the code there.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_*()` functions are already depreciated and removed in PHP 7.
I believe you are using PHP7. So that might be the reason you are getting that error.

So you better use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.summary.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

[image]

**EDIT**

Just noticed that you are using `mysqli_connect` function in your code! But your error message is saying about `mysql_connect` ! Are you sure that yo are not accidently using `mysql_connect()` function in your code? Have a look at your code present in `datatable.php` file at line #24.